# Executing exe using azure function cause Exception EAccessViolation in module comctl32.dll

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am using the C# Process.Start() to run an executable that uses the comctl32.dll. But when I deploy the function to Azure it exit of the executable with "Exception EAccessViolation in module comctl32.dll." Is there a way for my executable to get access to comctl32.dll or am I reading this error completely wrong? Do I need to set some permission on the executable itself so that it can access the resource?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions run within a [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) that enforces restrictions on what the app can access in the shared infrastructure.

For cases such as this, you should instead use a [custom image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli%2Cv1&pivots=programming-language-csharp) to run your function app. Functions on their own don't support running windows image but there is an image that you can use to build your container (refer [this issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/20976#issuecomment-449699243) for more details) and host in another service like

- [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-custom-container?tabs=dotnet&pivots=container-windows-azure-portal)
- [Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-overview)